# Как правильно писать phpunit тесты?

Tags: laravel5, phpunit

Учусь писать phpunit тесты , хочу попробовать на имеющемся коде написать тест мой код

```
<?php
class ContentService implements ContentServiceInterface
{
    private $client;

    /**
     * ContentServiceInterface constructor.
     * @param Client $client
     */
    public function __construct(Client $client)
    {
        $this->client = $client;
    }

    /**
     * @param $query
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getContent($query): ?string
    {
        $queryEncode = urlencode($query);

        if ($result = $this->loadFromCache($queryEncode)) {
            return $result['content'];
        }

        return null;
    }

    public function sqrt($x)
    {
        return sqrt($x);
    }

}
```

Вот мой пробный тест

```
    <?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use App\Services\ContentService;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use Tests\TestCase;

class ContentServiceTest extends TestCase
{
    public $client;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent:: __construct();


    }


    public function testsqrt($client): void
    {
        $o = new ContentService($client);
        $this->assertEquals(4, $o->sqrt(16));
    }
}
```

Получаю ошибку,ткните пальцем пожалуйста

> ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function Tests\Feature\ContentServiceTest::testsqrt(), 0 passed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При запуске тестов вызываются все функции, название которых начинается на test. Вызываются они, естественно, без аргументов (откуда системе тестов знать, что вы там хотели передать в $client ?).

Единственное исключение - наличие у функции тестирования провайдера данных (dataprovider). Это отдельная функция, которая поставляет данные в вашу testsqrt. Она должна быть описана через @dp.

А пока что система тестов вызывает  вашу testsqrt без аргументов и при вызове видит, что testsqrt нужен 1 аргумент. На этом тест и падает.